# How to generate Automatic Weights if not parenting?

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, weight-painting

When parenting a mesh to an armature, we are presented with some options, such as to generate Empty Groups, and to generate Automatic Weights.

[image: Parenting with Automatic Weights]

If we choose *not to parent* the mesh to the armature and instead add an Armature Modifier directly, we are not presented with these options.

[image: Add Modifier > Armature]

[image: Armature Modifier]

Is there a way to generate Automatic Weights or Empty Groups separately in the menu somewhere?

It's not a big deal since we can parent it and then unparent it and rearrange the hierarchy, I just feel like I should know how to do it without this extra step (if there's a way).

Thanks

Comment: Since it only makes sense when you try to deform mesh with bones, so it has to be like that, or you have to do it by scripting maybe. I'd say there is no shortcut currently. Maybe you can tell more about why you want to do that?

Comment: Yeah, I considered that too, but I thought maybe there was a way to generate this data from a selected mesh object to the active mesh object. I am working on [a rig and mesh that are both parented to a collision object for game use](https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/38/), and this is my first time working with this kind of setup, but it got me thinking more flexibly in terms of how rigs can be structured. So I thought it would be useful to know how to generate this data without changing the parenting hierarchy. I admit it's a nerdy question, and based more on curiosity than need.

Comment: It's not nerdy at all, it's very valid question to speed up workflow. I do not know an answer other than what you said in last paragraph, which is also the way I do it. Maybe this could be a feature request to optimize workflow. But when I think about it there are many more things in blender that should get a design review and an improvement.

Comment: For generating/transfering weights beween objects, you can: 1. use transfer data operator; 2. use "copy vertex group to selected" feature; 3. use Data Transfer modifier.

Comment: @LeonCheung Thanks for those ideas. I'll play with them.